# .htaccess - force a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a website (say, `www.domain.com`) and want to release part of the site (say, `www.domain.com/foo/`). How do I forcibly redirect users via .htaccess? Are there any SEO concerns about this? Would it be better if I just modified my application so that the part that is ready is accessible in the root domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will redirect anything to the location of your choice. (.*) matches 0 or more of any char.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo/ [flags]
```

SEO implications, I'm not certain of, but if you're only ready to release some parts of the site, then there's no issue there as the crawler will get the links you want it to. I'd advise sticking with the .htaccess solution instead of doing any modification as it leaves you free to add or change things more easily at a later stage.

Comment: For `flags`, you probably need to use `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: I don't want to redirect "anything" to a specific location. I just want to redirect attempts to access the root directory to a specific location. How do I do that?